# Create point in the origin of a CRS using PROJ.4

Tags: postgis

I know we can use [ST_TRANSFORM](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Transform.html) to transform a geometry into a different spatial reference system, which can be defined as a PROJ.4 string such as: `+proj=gnom +ellps=WGS84 +lat_0=52 +lon_0=0 +no_defs`. In my case I have a list of PROJ.4 strings with different origins but I don't have the actual ST_POINT of those origins and I would like to create a geometry based on that.

Is it possible to make a point on the origin of this projection, which would be equivalent to `ST_GeomFromText('POINT(0 52)',4326)`?

I tried `select st_transform(st_makepoint(0,0), '+proj=gnom +ellps=WGS84 +lat_0=52 +lon_0=0 +no_defs')` but it doesn't work. I was looking for something like this.

Comment: Is this a question about regex'ing the proj4 strings that you provide?

Comment: Not really. I wanted to ask if there is a way without processing the proj4 since the parameters are optional